# Delphi TStatusBar truncates the text at about 140 chars

Tags: delphi

I have a TStatusBar that contains two status panels. The first one is about 100 pixels long. The second one fills the rest of the status bar width. If I try to display in this second panel strings longer than about 140 chars, it truncates them to this value.

There is any way to get over this bug?

D7, Win XP

---

Edit: is 126 chars.

Comment: This is not an issue in Delphi 2007 running under Windows 7.

Comment: Have a look at the VCL source. It will tell you why this is happening.

Comment: 140 chars? Maybe it's twitter-enabled?  He, he...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@Altar, the [`TStatusBar`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TStatusBar) component, draw the text using the [`SB_SETTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760758%28VS.85%29.aspx) Windows message, this is limited to draw 127 characters in WinXP.

> lParam
>
> ```
> Pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the text to set.
> ```
>
> If wParam is SBT_OWNERDRAW, this
>   parameter represents 32 bits of data.
>   The parent window must interpret the
>   data and draw the text when it
>   receives the WM_DRAWITEM message. **In
>   Windows XP and earlier**, the text for
>   each part is limited to **127
>   characters**. This limitation has been
>   removed in Windows Vista.

As workaround you can draw the text of the statusbar yourself using the `OnDrawPanel` event.

see this sample wich draw a 200 char text in the second panel of an `TStatusBar`, don't forget set the property `Style` of the panel to `psOwnerDraw`

```
procedure TForm1.StatusBar1DrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar;
  Panel: TStatusPanel; const Rect: TRect);
var
 MyLongText: string;
 i         : Integer;
begin

  //fill an string with 200 chars
  MyLongText:= StringOfChar('-', 199)+'X';

  If Panel = StatusBar1.Panels[1] Then
      With StatusBar1.Canvas Do
        TextOut(Rect.left, Rect.top + 2, MyLongText) ;
End;
```